# Configuring SELinux permissions on (SVS-V) IPC Semaphores

Tags: linux, ipc, selinux

I have a bunch of programs which use IPC Semaphores to interact (semget).

One of the programs is an Apache module, which runs in (some sort of) restricted SELinux context (which I don't understand too well).

The module is capable of interacting with any regular files correctly, if of-course the files have their SELinux security context set appropriately.

However - when my (Module) goes to access the IPC Semaphore, the semget call fails with a EPERM. When SELinux is turned off, I don't get this error.

So - there is obviously something I need to do to set some sort of SELinux security context or something on the Semaphore for this to work. If it was a regular file, I could just call "chcon" on it. Since it's a System-V IPC Semaphore, I can't do that.

What can I do to make this work??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic steps to get [SELinux](http://www.selinuxproject.org/) working with the changes you need are:

1. Enable [permissive mode](http://www.selinuxproject.org/page/Guide/Mode)
2. Capture denials
3. Add a new policy module or modify an existing policy module
4. Enable enforcing mode and test

Exactly how to do these steps depends on what Linux distribution you are using; here are references for [CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux), [Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/SELinux), [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/hardened/selinux/selinux-handbook.xml), [RedHat](https://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6-Beta/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/index.html) and [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SELinux). You can also find SELinux information from [NSA](https://www.nsa.gov/research/_files/selinux/papers/module/t1.shtml). The best documentation I found is from Gentoo: [step 1](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/hardened/selinux/selinux-handbook.xml?part=2&chap=3), [step 2](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/hardened/selinux/selinux-handbook.xml?part=2&chap=3), [step 3](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/hardened/selinux/selinux-handbook.xml?part=2&chap=5), [step 4](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/hardened/selinux/selinux-handbook.xml?part=2&chap=4).

As [@smassey noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572974/configuring-selinux-permissions-on-svs-v-ipc-semaphores/7685340#7685340), you most probably need to modify some [IPC permission](http://seedit.sourceforge.net/doc/access_vectors/access_vectors.html#SECTION00044000000000000000).

Answer (score 0):

SELinux has persmission setting for more than just regular files, but also device and special files.

http://seedit.sourceforge.net/doc/access_vectors/access_vectors.html#SECTION00044000000000000000 is what you're looking for. Give read/write/etc permissions to the "sem" object.

Cheers