# Linux shared memory - shmget failing

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, shared-memory

I'm trying to share some memory from a producer process to a consumer process in linux (Ubuntu16).

There's just a common header which defines this small structure

```
struct my_small_pod_structure {
    void *handle;
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

The producer process is doing:

```
// Create a semaphore to synchronize
psem = sem_open ("producerSem", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 0);
sem_unlink ("producerSem"); // Avoid persisting after the process closed

shmkey = ftok("/dev/null", 5);

int shmid = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(my_small_pod_structure), 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
if (shmid < 0) {
    error("shmget failed");
    exit(1);
}


my_small_pod_structure *shared_ptr = (my_small_pod_structure*) shmat (shmid, NULL, 0);
// populate shared_ptr with the producer data here..
...

sem_post (psem); // data is ready

sleep(1000000); // very long value, assured that the producer isn't exiting before the consumer pulls it
```

While the consumer:

```
sem_t *psem = sem_open ("producerSem", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 0);
sem_unlink ("producerSem");

key_t shmkey = ftok("/dev/null", 5);
int shmid = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(my_small_pod_structure), 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
if (shmid < 0) {
    int error = errno;
    printf("shmget failed %d\n", error);
    exit(1);
}

sem_wait (psem); // wait for data to be ready

// DATA IS READY!

my_small_pod_structure *shared_ptr = (my_small_pod_structure*) shmat (shmid, NULL, 0);

// use shared_ptr..
...
```

but even though the producer starts BEFORE the consumer (although I suppose it shouldn't matter because of the semaphores), I'm just getting from the consumer

```
shmget failed 13
```

The producer seems to work and reach the sleeping point waiting for the consumer to pick it up.

What am I doing wrong? Why the 13 - permission denied?

Comment: Check the value of `errno` after `shmget` fails.  Should give you some clue.

Comment: @G.M. edited the question

Comment: Did you check that `ftok` did not return `-1`? Did you try with other `ftok` parameters? Are producer and consumer launched by the same user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shmat returns segmentation falut with errno=13(EACCES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463957/shmat-returns-segmentation-falut-with-errno-13eacces)

Comment: I tried to replicate your programs on a Fedora Linux workstation. The shmget does not return an error, but your semaphore calls appear to be wrong. If you call `sem_unlink` on the producer before the consumer runs, the consumer won't be able to open the same semaphore by name. If you call `sem_open` with `O_EXCL`, the second program to run will fail to open the existing semaphore.

Comment: @purplepsycho no they are not, I wonder if 0666 is the culprit here..

Comment: @FBergo You're right for O_EXCL, but why calling sem_unlink would prevent the consumer from accessing the semaphore? I thought its purpose was to just destroy the semaphore as soon as all the processes close it

Comment: @Dean according to the sem_unlink man page, the semaphore name is removed immediately, so any calls trying to open that semaphore by name after that will either fail or create a distinct semaphore with same name (while the old one is still open somewhere, but without a name).

Comment: @FBergo ugh you're right. If you post that as an answer I'll upvote it since it fixed another bug. It still doesn't explain the shmget though but I suppose those permissions might be the culprit, I'll test it out

Comment: Your shmget permission issue may be related to the selinux configuration (selinux can restrict access to the shm subsystem): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572974/configuring-selinux-permissions-on-svs-v-ipc-semaphores